# Updating array field in document with another array

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

In Laravel 5 with MongoDB and jenssegers I'm trying to update an document's Array field. But it's not updating.

When field contains Array[2] and I'm trying to update it with Array[1] it's not updating.
In otherhand another document fields are updating properly.

I checked scenarios:

```
old value | new value | result
---------------------------------
Array(1)  | Array(2)  | OK
---------------------------------
Array(1)  | null      | OK
---------------------------------
Array(1)  | Array(0)  | OK
---------------------------------
Array(2)  | Array(1)  | NO UPDATE
```

My document looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "default": 0,
    "variables": [
        {
            "name": "responsibilities",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "requirements",
            "type": "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my PHP code (I dealt with this in that way for now, but it's not elegant at all). What am I missing?

```
$document->name = $name;
$document->default = $default;
$document->variables = [];  // there is neccesity to clear this field first, because overriding with smaller array
$document->save();          // is faulty (for ex. when removing one variable)
$document->variables = $variables;
$document->save();
```

Comment: you can do some kind of setter like this https://laraveldaily.com/working-with-mysql-json-columns-in-laravel-custom-properties-example/

Comment: You're right, but that is just moving this one more db operation to another place.

Comment: https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/ check i think you can pass array to the update method

Comment: @DominikDominik have you got a solution? I'm also experiencing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074224/laravel-jenssegers-mongodb-nested-array-update-not-working

Comment: unfortunately I didn't found a solution. There is still @fixme comment in my code.